# Find the number of positive integers $n$ such that $n+ 2n^2 + 3n^3 +...+2005n^{2005} $ is divisible by $n−1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, divisibility

I tried to solve this problem by equating the given expression to a function $f(x)$ and concluding that if $(n-1)$ is a factor of $f(x)$, $f(1)$ must be equal to zero, which it isn't so I concluded that (n-1) can never be a factor of $f(x)$.
But when I tried to solve the problem by putting some values of $n$, I got that $n=2$ is a solution.
If anyone can correct me please do so.

Comment: $f(n)=n+2n^2+\ldots+2005n^{2005}=(n-1)q(n)+(1+2+...+2005)$ for some polynomial $q(n)$. Therefore $n-1$  divides $f(n)$ if and only if $n-1$ divides $1+2+...+2005=\frac{2005\cdot 2006}{2}=5\cdot 17\cdot 59\cdot 401$. The number of positive divisors of this number is $16$.

Comment: You confused the concept of polynomial factors and integer factors.

Comment: I think @Urtur solution is true if $q(n)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients, which can be proved easily.

Answer (score 1):

The problem statement is essentially "when does the *integer* $P(n)$ divide $Q(n)$?". So, for instance, $n+1$ divides $n+3$ where $n=1$, simply because $2$ divides $4$.

You interpreted this as "does the polynomial $P(n)$ divide $Q(n)$?" Note that I omitted the "when", because this statement no longer depends on $n$; it is a statement of the polynomials as a whole, not the individual values they obtain at different $n$'s.

I think you can finish this problem on your own once this is addressed.

Comment: As a subsidiary comment, I think it is not proper to just give a hint to the OP without finding out the real confusion. This actually rids him/her the chance of coming up with the idea on his/her own.

Comment: It is entirely on the hands of the OP to read or skip reading anything they want. So, nobody is being rid of anything. This website is more like a book and nothing like a classroom. Moreover, the content of any of the pages of this website is intended to serve any visitor and not only  the OP.